# Solution without words

Tags: logical-deduction, reverse-puzzling

**H**ere comes a series of snapshots in the life of a worksheet
that might come into play when solving *a variation of*
a fairly well-known numerical logic puzzle.
­
Parameters of the progenitor puzzle have been modified
to entail a less cumbersome solution.

**What specifically is the puzzle solved here?
    What are steps B through E?**

The puzzle has an oral component
but this sentence contains the last words presented here,
after which the worksheet will speak for itself,
beginning with a layout of potential answers.

```
 A.            7 --                   ?  ?
              6 --                ?  ?  ?  ?
             5 --             ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?
            4 --          ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?
           3 --       ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?
          2 --    ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?
         1 -- ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?
             /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /
            1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
```

```
 B1.           7 --                   1  1
              6 --                3  1  1  1
             5 --             1  2  1  2  1  1
            4 --          2  2  3  1  1  3  2  1
           3 --       2  3  1  2  1  3  1  2  1  3
          2 --    2  2  2  2  3  2  2  2  2  1  3  1
         1 -- 1  1  1  2  1  2  1  2  2  2  1  3  1  2
             /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /
            1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14


 B2.           * --                   .  .
              6 --                3  .  .  .
             5 --             .  2  .  2  .  .
            4 --          2  2  3  .  .  3  2  .
           3 --       2  3  .  2  .  3  .  2  .  3
          2 --    2  2  2  2  3  2  2  2  2  .  3  .
         1 -- .  .  .  2  .  2  .  2  2  2  .  3  .  2
             /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /
            *  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  * 12  * 14
```

```
 C1.          6 --                ?
             5 --                ?     ?
            4 --          ?  ?  ?       `?  ?
           3 --       ?  ?    `?     ?    `?     ?
          2 --    ?  ? `? `?  ? `?  ? `?  ?     ?
         1 --         `?    `?    `? `? `?     ?     ?
                /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /     /     /
               2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10    12    14


 C2.     5     7     9
          `.    `.    `.
            `.* --`.    `.        .
             *`.-   `.    `.     .     .
            4 --`.    `.  . `?  .       `.  .
           3 --   `.  . `?    `?     .    `.     .
          2 --    . `? `. `?  . `?  . `.  .     .
         1 --         `?    `?    `? `. `.     .     .
                /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /     /     /
               *  3  4  5  6  7  8  *  *     *     *
```

```
       D1.       4 --        20            D2.       4 --        20
                3 --     12   `18                   3 --     12   `18
               2 --  6    `10   `14                2 --  .    `10   `14
              1 --    `4    `6    `8              1 --    `4    `.    `8
                   /  /  /  /  /  /                    /  /  /  /  /  /
                  3  4  5  6  7  8                    *  4  5  6  7  8
```

```
       E1.       4 --        ?             E2.       * --        .
                3 --     ?    `?                    * --     .    `.
               2 --       `?    `?                 * --       `.    `.
              1 --     ?          `?              1 --     ?          `.
                      /  /  /  /  /                       /  /  /  /  /
                     4  5  6  7  8                       4  *  *  *  *
```

```
       F!            \   /

             1 ---->   !   <----

                     /   \
                    4
```

Comment: FYI I am *so close* to solving this. It's just the precise logic of C2 I need to suss... Will post my answer as soon as I've cracked that...

Comment: Thank you for gving this a look, @Stiv!
No doubt you've identified the puzzle so your comment made me unsure
about C2.  After rediagramming it i still don't see a mistake
but if there is one i'm sorry to say that it wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: I've definitely got the puzzle and I don't think there's an error - I just need to get all the semantics right in my explanation, since of course the exact words are vital to the success of the puzzle...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has taken quite some time to get my head around and is a bit tricky to write-up, but I believe I now finally have the answer. This is an analysis of a puzzle along the following lines:

> *I am thinking of two numbers whose sum is less than 16. I tell Alice their product and Bob their sum, and challenge them to tell me the two numbers.
>
>
>
>  Alice: "I don't know the two numbers."
>
>
>
>  Bob: "I knew that."
>
>
>
>  Alice: "In that case, I **do** know the numbers!"
>
>
>
>  Bob: "Oh, then now I do too!"*

---

**Solution in practice:**

> I told Alice that the product of my two numbers is 4, and I told Bob that their sum is 5.
>
>  Alice (who knows the product is 4) knows that the numbers must be 1 and 4 (in which case Bob was told sum 5) or 2 and 2 (in which case Bob was told sum 4). *She cannot tell which of these two is correct, and so says "I do not know".*
>
>  Bob (who knows the sum is 5) knows that the numbers must be 1 and 4 (in which case Alice was told product 4) or 2 and 3 (in which case Alice was told product 6). Bob reasons that if Alice was told product 4 she had two options: 1-4 and 2-2, and wouldn't be able to narrow them down; he also reasons that if Alice was told product 6 she had two options: 1-6 and 2-3, again unable to narrow them down. Whatever Alice was told, Bob knows *she could not know the answer for sure*!
>
>  This, however, gives Alice new information... *she now knows Bob must have been told sum 5*, since if he knew she couldn't *possibly* know, then for every possible number pair that summed to his known sum there must have existed *another* number pair with the same product (thereby preventing Alice from knowing for sure). If Bob was told sum 4 the two possible number pairs were 1-3 or 2-2 - *but no pair other than 1-3 has a product of 3*. In contrast, with Bob being told sum 5 the two possible number pairs are 1-4 and 2-3, which each have companion number pairs with the same product: 2-2 and 1-6. Bob must therefore have been told sum 5, and thus (as per her original logic) **the answer must be 1-4**.
>
>  Bob - knowing that Alice now knows the answer - *also now knows the answer must be 1-4*. After all, if it was 2-3 (his other option), Alice would have been told product 6 and would *still* have no way of differentiating between 1-6 and 2-3, unable to make the deduction she did in the previous step.

---

**Explaining the diagrams:**

With this in mind, we can now appreciate which steps of this process are reflected in the diagrams.

> First thing is to note that the diagrams reflect **our** logical deduction process to find the end solution. We do not have the benefit of knowing the product or the sum - we just know that *Alice* knows the product while *Bob* knows the sum... Thus we must consider all options that meet the initial criteria of summing to less than 16.
>
>  **A** reflects the initial state of play - we need to deduce which of the number pairs marked with a '?' is the correct answer. We have no information before anybody has made any statements.
>
>  **B1** displays, for each possible number pair, how many number pairs share the same product (e.g. 1-14 and 2-7 both show '2', since these are the 2 solutions with product 14). Alice saying she doesn't know the answer means we can remove all pairs who have a unique product (those marked with a '1'), which is what is depicted in **B2**.

```
 B2.           * --                   .  .
              6 --                3  .  .  .
             5 --             .  2  .  2  .  .
            4 --          2  2  3  .  .  3  2  .
           3 --       2  3  .  2  .  3  .  2  .  3
          2 --    2  2  2  2  3  2  2  2  2  .  3  .
         1 -- .  .  .  2  .  2  .  2  2  2  .  3  .  2
             /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /
            *  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  * 12  * 14
```

> **C1** and **C2** show the results of Bob's assertion that Bob already knew Alice couldn't possibly know - in particular, **C2** depicts us being able to reduce the possibilities further to only the three sum-values (5, 7 and 9) for which at least one other number pair existed with the same product, thereby rendering Alice's hoped of solving the puzzle initially impossible.

```
 C2.     5     7     9
          `.    `.    `.
            `.* --`.    `.        .
             *`.-   `.    `.     .     .
            4 --`.    `.  . `?  .       `.  .
           3 --   `.  . `?    `?     .    `.     .
          2 --    . `? `. `?  . `?  . `.  .     .
         1 --         `?    `?    `? `. `.     .     .
                /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /     /     /
               *  3  4  5  6  7  8  *  *     *     *
```

> **D1** now shows the products of the remaining number-pair possibilities. Since Alice was able to solve it at this point we know that the product cannot have been 6. **D2** depicts the two number-pairs with this product being chalked off.

```
 D1.       4 --        20            D2.       4 --        20
          3 --     12   `18                   3 --     12   `18
         2 --  6    `10   `14                2 --  .    `10   `14
        1 --    `4    `6    `8              1 --    `4    `.    `8
             /  /  /  /  /  /                    /  /  /  /  /  /
            3  4  5  6  7  8                    *  4  5  6  7  8
```

> **E1** now shows the remaining possibilities for Bob. Since he is able to solve it at this point we need the number-pair which has a unique sum among those remaining - that which sums to 5 (i.e. 1-4).

```
 E1.       4 --        ?             E2. & F!      * --        .
          3 --     ?    `?                        * --     .    `.
         2 --       `?    `?                     * --       `.    `.
        1 --     ?          `?                  1 ---->  !          `.
                /  /  /  /  /                           /  /  /  /  /
               4  5  6  7  8                           4  *  *  *  *
```

> Finally, this is corroborated in **F!** - we have our answer at last! Phew!

Comment: As well as solving this, @Stiv, you answered another hope: to explain the solution more clearly than does [WɪᴋɪᴘᴇᴅɪA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_and_Product_Puzzle#Explanation).
After moving an edit from a comment into the puzzle statement, what if i also intersperse your explanation with layouts A-F and bounty it?
It seems what i thought were ample clues (e.g, C2 & D1 were meant to convey the key words of the fairly-well-known puzzle's name; did that work for you? what did?
you certainly got how A presents the puzzle's parameters) still left a more-mysterious-than-intended puzzle.

Comment: @humn If you'd like to add the diagrams to improve the answer, feel free :) You know what, I didn't know this puzzle type even *had* a name! It was the realisation of what those steps represented that put me on the right track eventually though. I spent a long time weeks ago thinking it might be related to an optimal strategy for a board game - the truth only hit me at bedtime last night and then genuinely infiltrated my dreams! (That was one restless night...!)

Comment: **Note to mouse hoverers:
  Clicking inside a spoiler block keeps it visible after you hover off.**
(Sorry, @Stiv, when i tried to add diagrams without breaking up the spoiler
 block, `<pre>...</pre>` triggered a spoiler bug and `<code>...</code>` rendered
 with ughly stripes. Rollback the edit, of course, if you don't like the spoiler
 block broken up.
 Or... maybe you - anyone else? - know something more about this.)

Comment: @humn Better this way than with buggy spoilers :) I'll take a look on a laptop later to see if anything else works better... Thanks.